# ¿Cómo puedo traer y actualizar un dato con una sola consulta usando Mongoose?, por ejemplo algo así

Tags: javascript, mongoose

estoy trabajando con mongoose y tengo el siguiente problema.
Actualmente tengo dos Schema's.

Con el primer Schema guardo el singup de usuario.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, trim: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    saldo:{ type: Number, required: false }, //Inicia en 0
  }
);
```

Con el siguiente esquema Data estoy guardando y asociando el ID del usuario que me da el Schema User a una posición.

```
const DataSchema = new Schema(
  {
    idRegister: { type: String, required: true },
    pos: { type: String, unique: true, require: true }//formato ("0,0")
  {
```

La ejecución comienza cuando me dan una pos (ejemplo=>("0,0")) y un una cantidad x de saldo y tengo que buscar cual es el ID del usuario asociado a esta pos y sumarle el saldo al que ya tenia anteriormente este usuario.

Entonces hago la consulta así.

```
await DataSchema.find({ pos: pos })//busco con la pos para saber cual es el ID DEL USUARIO asociado a esa pos.
   .then(async (consulta)=>{
       //Cuando esta consulta se resuelve, 
       //ya puedo acceder al idRegister ya que consulta tiene dos propiedades: 
       //(idRegister, pos)
   
       //entonces nuevamente hago otra consulta para saber la cantidad de saldo del usuario 
       //ya que conozco cual es su ID
       
       //Busco en UserSchema el ID (consulta.idRegister)
       await UserSchema.find({ consulta.idRegister })
           .then((consultaSaldo)=>{//La cantidad de saldo esta en consultaSaldo.saldo

               //ahora actualizo el saldo sumando el saldo que ya tenía con el nuevo saldo
               await UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(consulta.idRegister, { saldo: consultaSaldo.saldo + newSaldo})
           })
})
```

Como se puede observar es un poco ineficiente.

Mi pregunta es cómo optimizar esto o cómo puedo traer y actualizar un dato con una sola consulta, por ejemplo algo así.

```
Donde el saldo toma el dato de la misma consulta, y le suma newSaldo y luego hace el Update.

await DataSchema.find({ pos: pos })
   .then(async (consulta)=>{
       await UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(consulta.idRegister, { saldo: saldo + newSaldo})
                                                                          ^
//                                              ---saldo que ya trae de la misma consulta---

//Es como si invocara desde la misma consulta el saldo que ya trae, 
//espero se entienda y muchas gracias de antemano
    })
})
```

Comment: Edité mi respeusta porque me di cuenta de que se podía hacer con una sola consulta. No hace falta usar `find` para hallar la `id` y luego usar esa `id` en un `findByIdAndUpdate`. Puedes hacer todo con un solo `findOneAndUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso particular lo puedes optimizar usando el operador `$inc` para incrementar el valor de un campo:

```js
await UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate({pos: pos}, {$inc: {saldo: newSaldo})
```